# My app is freezing after running for 20 min

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-handler, android-camera2, back-stack

I have an application which runs a stack of activities-fragment; A > a1:fragment > B > C, automatically. Activity A and its fragment is the android.hardware.camera2, which I have added to my app as a library. In order to run the stack of activities automatically I have a handler in activity A for photo capture and a handler in activity C which launches activity A:

Pass from activity A to fragment a:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_A);
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, a.newInstance()).commit();
    }
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
}
```

Handler for photo capture and pass from fragment a to activity B:

```
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {   
@Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn.callOnClick();
            }
        }, 5000);
       }

@Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            selectedPhotoPath2 = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), B.class);
            launchIntent.putExtra("uriFile2", selectedPhotoPath2);
            getActivity().startActivity(launchIntent);
            getActivity().finish();
                if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pass from activity B to activity C:

```
String packageName = this.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent2 = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    try {
        launchIntent2 = new Intent(this,Class.forName("com.example.ediamanti.imageprocessing.activities.C"));
    launchIntent2.putExtra("uriFile3", path);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(launchIntent2);
    finish();
```

Pass from activity C back to A:

```
final Handler handler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    handler2.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

My code is working fine but it freezes on activity A after 20 min of running. I would like to have the app running for more than an hour. When the activity freezes, no error message appears in the Logcat, while I can go back to the main menu of the application, so the activity freezes but the app is not crashing.

I have tried different approaches to solve the issue:

- Use of different combination of FLAGS in activity C (CLEAR_TOP, NEW_TASK etc.) to clear the back stack history.
- Remove bundles when passing intents to avoid exceeding bundle transaction limit.
- Change the logger size per log buffer of the mobile device from 256KB to 16MB.
- Vary handlers´waiting time.

but none of them seems to be the solution to my problem.

Does anyone have any idea of how this could be solved or any suggestion of which steps I could follow to search for the bug?Thanks!

Android monitor main thread: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzOKR.png)

Comment: Check is something running on main thread? go to the Monitor section and check process which is continuously running on main thread

Comment: Yes there is something running on the main thread. I have added the corresponding monitor section in my question.

Comment: can we done our work in background thread and take response on main thread like using asynctask something?

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi I am not sure if I understand very well what you are proposing. Which of these methods could run in background thread? Some of them, all of them? And how could this solve the problem? Could you please explain in more detail your comment?

Comment: this will help you : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html